# HTML onclick and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link like this.

```
<a href="board.php?id={$id}" onclick="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'board.php?id={$id}', type: 'ajax'});">
```

If the JavaScript is disabled, the browser can use the `href` value to load the page. But, if the JavaScript is enabled, the `onclick` and the `href` will work together. How can I prevent this? I want the `href` not to work when the JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: perhaps "this.preventDefault();" or "return false;" might work (inside the onclick) but I personally would handle the click event inside a javascript file or outside of the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either `event.preventDefault()` or a `false` return value:

```
<a href="board.php?id={$id}" onclick="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'board.php?id={$id}', type: 'ajax'});event.preventDefault();">

or 

<a href="board.php?id={$id}" onclick="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'board.php?id={$id}', type: 'ajax'});return false;">
```

Really, though, you shouldn't use inline event handlers like this. You should give your link an `id` or `class` and attach the handler to it like this:

```
<a href="board.php?id={$id}" id="myElement">something</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById('myElement').onclick = function () {
        parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'board.php?id={$id}', type: 'ajax'});
        event.preventDefault();
    };
</script>
```

This will make it ***much*** easier to read and maintain down the road.

Here's a simple [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/4hy01tnc/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`.

```
<a href="board.php?id={$id}" onclick="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'board.php?id={$id}', type: 'ajax'});return false;">
```

OR
Using jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop redirect
    // Your code here
});
```